# Multiple classes with multiple images

Tags: css, image, class, background, background-image

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
.box {
    background-image: url(../img/box.png);
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 90px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 831px;
}

.shadow_1 {
    background-image: url(../img/shadow_1.png);
    background-position: 0 100%; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-bottom: 31px;
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<div class="box shadow_1"></div>
```

I'd like to combine two classes with two different images, but have  the image in the second class override the first one. Is it even possible, or I have to use two `divs`?

Comment: Depending on which versions of IE you need to support, you may be able to make use of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements for adding extra backgrounds to a single element (not sure on IE7 support, but it works in IE8+)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest loaded styles will overwrite previously loaded styles.  So in your case.  Any styles in `.box` will be overwritten by style `.shadow_1` in your implementation.

You are correct in your assuming you will need another div to handle this.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply ;) Propably i'd have to consider two divs because of mighty IE but i was wondering if it is possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to have multiple background images on the same element. It is possible and supported in all latest browser versions, although if you want to support IE8 and earlier you have to use multiple divs.

```
 .box {
    background-image: url(../img/box.png), url(../img/shadow_1.png);
    background-position: 0 0, 0 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 90px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 831px;
    padding-bottom: 31px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i know that, but i wanted to be able do couple of shadow classes and add them to different boxes, so hardcoding mupltiple backgrounds is not solution for me ;) Thanks anyway ;)